# How can I generate object keys?

Tags: php

I have a string, which I parse into JSON sub-objects. for example, I have "me-name-first", exploded:

```
$string = explode('-', "me-name-first");
```

In json, I have the following order:

```
$json = json_decode('{"me":{"name":{"first":"John","last":"Doe"}}}');
```

I want to create dynamically the order, and update it in case one of the keys are missing. so instead of writing:

```
$json = $json->{$string[0]}->{$string[1]}->{$string[2]}; // and so on, can be even 99
```

I want to do it automatically:

```
$int = 0;
foreach($json as $key=>$value)
{
    if($key === $string[$int])
    {
        // great, iterate over childs,
        // and once the iteration ends,
        // return the last one's value

        $json = /* Last value, equals to $json->{$string[?]}->{$string[?]}->{$string[?]} ... */;
    }
    $int++;
}
```

How can I do it?

I tried to wrap it with a function but it returned an infinite loop.

Thank you

Comment: When you say "last", you seem to have multiple, do you mean you want to end up with an array at the end like `['John', 'Doe']`? So the same as `[$json->me->name->first, $json->me->name->last]` without knowing what the `branches` to the end `leaves` are?

Comment: @simandsim no it must go directly, so if first will be object too it goes according to string. i'll give another example: `foo-bar-foobar-baz` and json: `{"foo":{"bar":{"foobar":{"baz":1},"baz":{"foobar":"etc"}}}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over `$string` until you've processed the deepest nesting level:

```
$string = explode('-', "me-name-first");
$json = json_decode('{"me":{"name":{"first":"John","last":"Doe"}}}');

$value = $json;
while (count($string) > 0) {
    $key = array_shift($string);
    $value = $value->$key;
}

var_dump($value);
// string(4) "John"
```

This assumes that `$string` will always be compatible and will never contain something that's not part of the json object, like `"me-name-middle"` when `name` only contains `first` and `last`.

If you need to account for situations like that, this solution is probably too simplistic an approach.